# How do you disable a laptop display while using an external display?

Tags: windows, display, thinkpad

I've got my R50e Thinkpad hooked up to an external monitor.  But I don't need the laptop display.  How do I switch it off?  Only thing I can see is two display devices listed in Device Manager.
If I uninstall them would this do the trick or is this a BIOS thing?

I'm using fully patched Windows 2000.

Answer (score 2):

What OS? With W7 you can use WIN-P to show external display options, one of which is "Projector only". Otherwise, I think you need some extra monitor management software.

Answer (score 1):

**How to use the function (Fn) keys on the keyboard - ThinkPad R50e**

**Fn + F7**

Switch a display output location

```
* External monitor (CRT display)
* Computer display and external monitor (LCD + CRT display)
* Computer display (LCD)
```

[Source](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-53130.html)

*using Fn + F7 once should have the desired effect.*

Comment: I should have mentioned I have used Fn+F7 but I just get the same display on both.  Currently I've managed to extend the display so at least both are being used productively but would be nice to know how to disable it totally.

Comment: "Currently I've managed to extend the display" ... did you read the footnote? with extended desktop enabled, Fn + F7 does NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

With most laptops you can cycle through the different monitor modes (internal, external, both) by using the Fn key and a F# key combination I think the R50e uses Fn+F7.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Thinkvantage Presentation Manager on your machine, you should be able to set up you displays the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried holding down Fn and pressing F7 more than once (since it cycles between more than two modes)?    You may need to wait a few seconds between each press of F7.

What happens when you do this?

Comment: Cheers I'll give this a go.  Have to admit rocking two monitors right now is kind of handy, I'll see how I cope with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, Thinkpads have a bit of software called (iirc) presentation manager that'll take care of it.